# I want joint.js library to read my JSON and display it as a cell: rect and circle

Tags: javascript, json, jointjs

I have a json data structure like this for example :

```
var json1 = {
"places": [ { "id":0, "x":0.0, "y":0.0, "width":10.0, "height":10.0 },
            { "id":1, "x":50.0, "y":0, "width":10.0, "height":10.0 },
            { "id":2, "x":0.0, "y":30.0, "width":10.0, "height":10.0 },
            { "id":3, "x":50.0, "y":30.0, "width":10.0, "height":10.0 } ],
"transitions": [ { "id":0, "x":20.0, "y":20.0, "width":20.0, "height":10.0, "label":"Hello" } ],
"ptlinks": [ { "src":0, "dst":0, "expr":"x=0" },
             { "src":1, "dst":0, "expr":"y=0" } ],
"tplinks": [ { "src":0, "dst":1 },
             { "src":0, "dst":3 } ],
"name"": "Client"
}
```

I want to use these data to draw a graph with element transition as a rectangle and place as a circle with the links ....

```
    <script language="javascript">
var graph = new joint.dia.Graph;


var paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
    el: $('#main_petri'),
    width: 960,
    height: 500,
    model: graph
});

var rect = new joint.shapes.basic.Rect({
    position: { x: 100, y: 30 },
    size: { width: 100, height: 30 },
    attrs: { rect: { fill: '#FFFFFF' }, text: { text: '#', fill: '#000000' } }
});
    var rect2 = rect.clone();
rect2.translate(0,50);

var link = new joint.dia.Link({
        source: { id: rect.id },
        target: { id: rect2.id }
    });
graph.addCells([rect, rect2, link]);
```

How can I use JSON (position, size ...) into jointjs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just loop over your places/transitions and links and create JointJS elements/links. Something like:

```
_.each(json1.places, function(p) {
    graph.addCell(new joint.shapes.pn.Place({
        id: 'place' + p.id,
        position: { x: p.x, y: p.y },
        size: { width: p.width, height: p.height }
    }));
});
_.each(json1.transitions, function(t) {
    graph.addCell(new joint.shapes.pn.Transition({
        id: 'transition' + t.id,
        position: { x: t.x, y: t.y },
        size: { width: t.width, height: t.height },
        attrs: { '.label': { text: t.label } }
    }));
});
_.each(json1.ptlinks, function(l) {
    graph.addCell(new joint.dia.Link({
        source: { id: 'place' + l.src },
        target: { id: 'transition' + l.dst },
        labels: [ { position: .5, attrs: { text: { text: l.expr } } } ]
    }));
});
_.each(json1.tplinks, function(l) {
    graph.addCell(new joint.dia.Link({
        source: { id: 'transition' + l.src },
        target: { id: 'place' + l.dst },
        labels: [ { position: .5 } ]
    }));
});
```

Comment: I know it's not a place to post this comment, but I don't understand why I can't 'ask question' ... 'Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account.' The explanation is 'Stack Exchange has automatic filters in place to ban questions from accounts that have contributed many low-quality questions in the past ...', great.